# Equipment and Services that turns DIGITAL images into 35mm negatives

Tags: equipment-recommendation, film, 35mm, digital-vs-film

Help! I'm working with a company looking to transfer digital images in film format so they can more easily reprint from film (larger sizes etc).

I have been tasked with finding any and all equipment or companies that can do this, and I don't know where to begin as my background is marketing not photography. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction. IF this is something you do offer as a service, I'd love to know more about pricing etc.

Thanks!

Comment: No matter how you do it, transferring a digital image onto film will not magically give you higher resolution to print at larger sizes than you could direct from digital. It may reduce the appearance of pixelization at larger sizes due to the introduction of film grain that will obscure the pixel edges to some degree, but it will not increase the amount of resolvable detail at all.

Comment: Understood, but still have to compile a list of equipment and vendors....

Comment: Tell them to think again. What they are asking is "how to spend money to achieve nothing?" Printing directly from digital is far simpler these days than from film, & transferring one asset type to another will gain **no** new information.

Comment: [Is it possible and/or a good idea to print digital photos to slides?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/18678/75526) / [How can I create film slides from digital photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/69246/75526) / [Are there consumer/prosumer-level digital-to-film or digital-to-photo-paper projectors/enlargers?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/102023/75526) / [Is there any printer that can print digitally onto 35mm film?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/88556/75526)

Comment: There are many things this site does well, and many it does not work for. "Please compile a list of commercial options" is solidly in the latter category.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every service I'm aware of that produces large format prints from film will initially scan your film into a digital file anyway. Cutting out the middle man will allow you to use a color-managed workflow and most likely produce better outcomes.

That being said, you can either go with a service that performs digital to film conversion for the film industry (film-out service), though these are rapidly vanishing. The biggest is called CineLab I believe, you'll want one that provides a 70mm or 120mm service if you want to preserve as much of resolution modern digital cameras can provide as possible.

As far as procuring your own equipment, for high resolution, you're looking at a laser based system (Kodak makes, or at least made, one called the Lightning II or Arri makes the Arrilaser) or a DLP film recorder. Any of these you're talking very big money.

You might also see if your preferred printer provides printing to a large-format transparency film as an intermediate.

Again, I advise against using this method as the lost in quality by taking digital with all its flaws, then projecting that onto film with all its flaws, then putting it through film scanning with all its flaws, and finally printing all those compounded flaws through your output medium with all it's flaws... you get the point.

If the desire to go through film is artistic. Shooting on film, then scanning and doing whatever graphic design is desired, will give you the "look and feel" of film that will carry over into the final product better than taking a digital image and putting it on film in the middle of the process.